# Why is $\epsilon_0$ in Coulomb’s law permittivity of free space if since the free space has nothing (unlike the old concept of ether)?

Tags: electromagnetism, coulombs-law, physical-constants

Also why did Griffiths in his book said that “The constant $\epsilon_0$ is  called (ludicrously) the permittivity of free space”? What was he trying to say? Please lead. Thank you.

Comment: Epsilon-sub-zero can be written \epsilon_0.

Comment: Did *he* think the name is ludicrous or do *you* think so? It would help to quote exactly what the book says. (I personally think the name is very confusing.)

Comment: Changing units changes the value of $\epsilon_0$. Now reconsider your rant.

Comment: @G.Smith he actually used the word

Comment: When you use Gaussian units, the entire concept of “permittivity of free space” disappears. So it doesn’t have any physical meaning.

Comment: Using ‘ludicrously’ is a definite sign this is a rant, not a sober minded question.

Comment: @JonCuster well it’s not my word. David J Griffiths himself used the word in his book and I was asking why he used it.Maybe you misunderstood.

Comment: That's why it's better to actually quote the book instead of simply retelling. This will avoid any confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The permittivity of free space was named when people still accepted the aether. One might think it ludicrously named since we keep the name when we have removed the concept by which it was named. I had grown used to the convention that in natural units $\epsilon_0 = 1$, meaning that it is just a conversion constant for units of charge to conventional units which refer to force. Now it depends on the fine structure constant, which is a measured quantity referring to the likelihood of the exchange of a photon between charged particles, not anything specifically to do with the vacuum or free space.

Answer (score 2):

> Why is $ϵ_0$ in Coulomb’s law permittivity of free space if since the free space has nothing (unlike the old concept of ether)?

It's the consequence of how we've defined our unit of charge, the [coulomb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coulomb). In other systems of units the numeric value of $\varepsilon_0$ may be different. In particular, in [Gaussian system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_units#Unit_of_charge) it could be taken as $\varepsilon_0=\frac1{4\pi}$. There's no concept of "permittivity of free space" there at all, so the Coulomb's law has a simpler form, without any special constant.

Comment: So, it would mean that it doesn’t have any significance and is just mathematical.

Comment: @AshishKumar yes, it doesn't, aside from being a dimensionful constant just as the [gravitational constant $G$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravitational_constant).

Comment: However, Gaussian units demonstrate that there is no reason it *has* to be dimensionful.

Comment: @G.Smith if we happen to be in a different universe, so 1 method to know would be to take 2 charges and measure the force bw them which will happen to be diff due to diff value of epsilon-0 since it has diff space time fabric and nance diff permittivity.Is the above hypothesis correct?

Comment: @AshishKumar you'd have to make sure you've taken _the same_ charges. But there's no reference to be sure, unless you can teleport the charges between universes without changes.